# beautiful soup printing ng-href

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i have this piece of elements: `<a class="text-name username ng-binding" ng-href="https://www.roblox.com/users/18734213/profile" ng-bind="resaleRecord.seller.name" href="https://www.roblox.com/users/18734213/profile">RobotronicDude</a>`

im trying to print the first ng-href using beautiful soup
but it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maxva\Desktop\Python Projects\LimSniepr\LimSniper.py", line 24, in <module>
    ta = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'text-name username ng-binding'})[0]['ng-href']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

my code that i tried:

````
id = input("Enter a id to snipe: ")

url = f'https://www.roblox.com/catalog/{id}/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

ta = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'text-name username ng-binding'})[0]['ng-href']
print(ta)```
````

Comment: if you keep class as only 'username' and try ?? does it still throw the error ??

Comment: i mean , like so - `soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'username'})[0]['ng-href']`

Comment: yes it still does

Comment: then most probably it is dynamic content on the page you're requesting - meaning page content loads from javascript . in that case you might have to try `requests-html` library instead of `requests` library . reference for library - https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/

Comment: What do you get if you try `print(len(soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'text-name username ng-binding'})))`?

Comment: im not using requests im using beautifulsoup....

Comment: also it prints 0 @JackFleeting

Comment: So I guess you'll need to edit your question and show your url.

Comment: hey i edited it

Comment: @Max Do you want to get username? For example, from this URL https://www.roblox.com/catalog/18734213/ `Invinciblee` ?

Comment: i wanna get the url of their profile wich u see in the html element
https://prnt.sc/u5pyzs https://prnt.sc/u5pzfx https://www.roblox.com/catalog/321570512/Chill-Cap

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you talking about the reseller profile? The link you provide and the image are not the same.

Comment: @JackFleeting If you want to get the username use the roblox API. Here's the link: https://users.roblox.com/v1/users/enter here the id

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect why it happens with printing a list you get after parsing. Following code works fine:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """\
<a class="text-name username ng-binding" ng-href="https://www.roblox.com/users/18734213/profile" ng-bind="resaleRecord.seller.name" href="https://www.roblox.com/users/18734213/profile">RobotronicDude</a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, features="lxml")

for item in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'text-name username ng-binding'}):
    print(item['ng-href'])
```

Also may be it turns out that you have not correct url, so I higly recommend to use `soup.prettify` to inspect this